# pagination with search form in flask

Tags: flask

I am trying to paginate with the search option using flask.
my code is working. but when I am searching like "tool1" then it is showing on three pages.

If I am clicking on 2nd or next page link then it is refreshing my page with all data which is a total of 8 rows in my table.

Searched data should show 2 records per page on clicking any page number.

what I have to correct here?

**main. py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for
import flask
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter
import json
import dbConnect
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "logger@!#$%^"

@app.route("/home",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    toolName = None
    if "toolname" in request.form:
        toolName = request.form["toolname"]

    solution_data = solution_result(toolName)
    return render_template("home.html",solution_data=solution_data[0],pagination=solution_data[1])


def solution_result(toolName):

    # Setting page, limit and offset variables
    per_page = 2
    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    offset = (page - 1) * per_page

    cursor = dbConnect.ConnectDatabase()

    # Executing a query to get the total number of products
    if toolName:
        total_sql = sql = "select tool from error_history where tool=%s"
        cursor.execute(total_sql,(toolName))
        total = cursor.fetchall()
    else:
        total_sql = sql = "select tool from error_history"
        cursor.execute(total_sql)
        total = cursor.fetchall()

    # execute SQL query using execute() method.
    if toolName:
        sql = "select id, tool, error from error_history where tool=%s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"
        cursor.execute(sql,(toolName,per_page, offset))
    else:
        sql = "select id, tool, error from error_history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"
        cursor.execute(sql,(per_page, offset))

    result = cursor.fetchall()

    # Setting up the pagination variable, where you are using len(total) to set the total number of 
    # items available
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, offset=offset, total=len(total), 
    record_name='products',css_framework='bootstrap3')

    dbConnect.closeConnection()
    return result, pagination

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**dbConnect.py**

```
import pymysql
client = None
def ConnectDatabase():
    try:
        global client
        # Open database connection
        client = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","","solution")
        # makes autocommit false
        client.autocommit(False)
        # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        cursor = client.cursor()
        #print("******** database connected ****")
        return cursor
    except:
        print("******** database not connected ****")

def closeConnection():
    global client
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ConnectDatabase()
```

**solution.error_history table**

```
CREATE TABLE `error_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tool` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `error_history` (`id`, `tool`, `error`) VALUES
(1, 'tool1', 'error in toola'),
(2, 'tool2', 'error in toole'),
(3, 'tool3', 'error in place'),
(4, 'tool1', 'error in toolh'),
(5, 'tool1', 'error in toolo'),
(6, 'tool1', 'error in tool123'),
(7, 'tool1', 'error in toolxy'),
(8, 'tool2', 'error in toolxyz');

ALTER TABLE `error_history`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `error_history`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="DataLogger">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Data</title>

    <style>
        .pagination-page-info {
            padding: .6em;
            padding-left: 0;
            width: 40em;
            margin: .5em;
            margin-left: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .pagination-page-info b {
            color: black;
            background: #6aa6ed;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding: .1em .25em;
            font-size: 150%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="wrapper">
    {% block content %}

     <div id="Sidebar">

     </div>

    <!-- Page Content Holder -->
     <div id="content" >



        <p class="" style="font-weight: bold;">Dashboard</p>

        <div class="row">
            <form  name="searchForm" action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="POST" >
                <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                   <input type="input" class="form-control" id="toolname" name="toolname" placeholder="Search tool"
                          value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <div class="row col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12">
            {{ pagination.info }}
        </div>
        <div class="row  table-responsive col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12">

            <table class="table table-bordered solutionTable ">
            <thead class="">
              <tr>
                <th>Sl No.</th>
                <th>Tool</th>
                <th>error</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for row in solution_data %}

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{loop.index + (pagination.page - 1) * pagination.per_page }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
                     </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
        <div class="row  col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12">
            {{ pagination.links }}
        </div>
        <!-- Page Content Holder --> 
    </div>
     {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```